# Fuse lib example deleted my home folder

Tags: c, filesystems, fuse

I was playing with a modified version of https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/passthrough.c and I mounted it in a folder in my home directory (home/joao/mnt). Without realizing that I was running it already, I re-ran the fuse programm and my computer stopped working. I rebooted the system and then I saw my home folder without most of the files that ithad before. Is there anything I can do to restore my old state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no way an expert, but I'm afraid you've lost everything unless you have a backup of your system... I can only give a hint. In passthrough.c it is said that

> This file system mirrors the existing file system hierarchy of the
>    system, starting at the root file system. This is implemented by  just "passing through" all requests to the corresponding user-space libc functions. Its performance is terrible.

So, if I understood it right, every change you're applying to mounted passthrough FS affects your home dir. Or, since it mirrors your home dir, you could just make a pretty recursion by mounting it there and thus break something.